# Sending a password unencrypted over the Internet

Tags: security, networking

I cannot receive an SSL certificate for an ODBC database connection between my local machine and my hosting service.  If I know my network is secure and my hosting service's network is secure, how worried should I be about data being intercepted between our two connections?  In this situation is there any other way to retrieve data securely?

Comment: John Feminella's solution would have worked, until my service provider denied my access!  Good to know in the future!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty much the perfect use case for SSH. Set up a tunnel and then make a connection that way. [**Here's a tutorial**](http://www8.pair.com/dmurdoch/mysql.html) for an ODBC connection from Windows to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without knowing what you mean by yours and your provider's network being secure. If you are not transferring over some sort of encrypted connection (such as ssl), it would be possible for your communication to be captured - of course depending on where the traffic is.